# How do serializables work in .net?

Tags: c#, .net

What happens when I annotate a class with serializable? Can I serialize them into json or XML? How is this done?

Comment: Awefully broad and google-able question.

Comment: Oded with 53K of score chose to tell answer me and you down voted me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`SerializableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) is just a marker attribute that does nothing.

When using it, you are claiming that every component of your class can be serialized - in order to actually serialize the class you need to use a serializer such as the XmlSerializer or [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx).

To use the `DataContractSerializer`, you need to decorate your classes and class members with different attributes (`DateMemberAttribute`, for example). It give you better control over the output XML than the `XmlSerializer` does and can also output [JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx).

Comment: It's not a marker interface, because it's not an interface. It's an attribute.

Comment: I think he's referring to the general term where it's a run time marker.

Answer (score 0):

This allows the class to be serialized with the available serializers, like xmlserializer and the binary serializer. However, more annotations are probably required to output it in the desired xml layout (or JSON)

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx#objserializ_topic4)

Comment: `XmlSerializer` does not care about `SerializableAttribute`.